# ofBiz multi-tenant setup but can't login to tenant?

Tags: multi-tenant, ofbiz

I've followed [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/OFBIZ/multitenancy-support.html) to setup ofBiz multitenant and can log in to the default, but not to tenant DEMO1, or DEMO2. I did the following:

```
svn co https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ofbiz/trunk ofbiz.12.04-tenants
cd ofbiz.12.04-tenants
./ant
java \-Xmx512m \-XX:MaxPermSize=128m \-jar ofbiz.jar \-install \-readers=seed \-    delegator=default
java \-Xmx512m \-XX:MaxPermSize=128m \-jar ofbiz.jar \-install \-readers=seed \-delegator=default#DEMO1
java \-Xmx512m \-XX:MaxPermSize=128m \-jar ofbiz.jar \-install \-readers=seed \-delegator=default#DEMO2
./ant load-demo-multitenant
```

Change the multitenant option to Y with vi, below.

```
vi framework/common/config/general.properties
./ant start
```

When I log in with admin, ofbiz and blank TenantID I am allowed into ofBiz. When I log in with admin, ofbiz and DEMO1 (or DEMO2) TenantID I get:

```
The Following Errors Occurred: 
following error occurred during login: User not found.
```

I wonder if I missed some configuration steps to turn on readers for Tenants DEMO1 and DEMO2.

Answer (score 0):

Please pardon my previous post, it's working now. I went to a different machine and followed this procedure:

```
svn co https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ofbiz/trunk ofbiz.12.04-tenants 
cd ofbiz.12.04-tenants 
./ant load-demo-multitenant
```

Change multitenant to Y in the following.

```
vi framework/common/config/general.properties 
./ant start 
http://localhost:8080/catalog
```

I am now able to login to admin, ofbiz, default; DEMO1 and DEMO2.